# vue reactive find array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

There is an array like the one below in merhava vue js, and when I send deletefuction(2) of it, I want to learn the index order of the data that is actually `id` 2, but I can't find it, where am I doing the search wrong?

```
{
 id:1,
 name:'hello',
},
{
 id:2,
     name:'about',
},
{
 id:3,
     name:'contact',
}
```

```
const state = reactive({
 postList: [],
});

function deleteFuncton(idx) {
 const found = state.postList.find(element => element.id === idx)
 console.log(found)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to delete element from array, or if you just want to find index use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const { reactive } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      postList: [{id:1, name:'hello'}, {id:2, name:'about'}, {id:3, name:'contact'}]
    })
    function deleteFuncton(idx) {
      //const found = state.postList.findIndex(p => p.id === idx)
      //console.log(found)
      state.postList = state.postList.filter(p => p.id !== idx)
    }
    return {
      state, deleteFuncton
    }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="item in state.postList">
    {{ item }}
    <button @click="deleteFuncton(item.id)">del </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm going to splice, it won't work that way.